# CSS background cover

Tags: html, css, mobile, background

I have a full screen background accomplished perfectly in CSS using:

```
body {
  background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/<image>.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden
  }
```

Although when looking at this on mobile, iOs & IE Windows Mobile, the background is tiled instead of full screen.  I get I may need to have a different CSS file for the mobile OSs out there but am unsure of what exactly the problem is, how do I full screen an image for mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Change your background-image to this:

```
background: url('../images/backgrounds/<image>.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

When this won't work, please take a look at the [article by CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) about a prefect full page background image.

There are only CSS solutions as well as solutions with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

That might be a resolution problem, get screen size variables and strech the image to fill the screen.

And try it with adding *background-repeat:no-repeat;*

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cover that repeats x-y wise. So it is really a trick with a background image and colors in the css that corespond..

```
    body {
     background: url("images/bg3.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #EF9360;
    }
```

So if your css background image is blue on the top you should use a blue background...

Read more here
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image_gradient1